# Having trouble directing multiple variables into the correct lists

Tags: python, list

I am attempting to make this program check what grade a students score falls under and then print their name and score and that grade list.

I have the score list assignment part working but am unable to make a students name "follow" their score into the same list.

```
st1 = '13'
st2 = '3'
st3 = '17'
n1 = 'john'
n2 = 'mary'
n3 = 'rob'

A , B = [], []
a = str ([st1, st2, st3])

def listselect (a) :
    sn = 'student name-'
    f = 'score-'
    for element in a :
        if element in ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9') :
            if element in st1:
                A.append (n1)
            if element in st2:
                A.append (n2)
            if element in st3:
                A.append (n3)

        else : B.append (sn+f+element)  

listselect (a)
print (A, '\n', B)
```

```
The ideal outcome would be
[John, 3] #A grade

[Mary, 13, Rob, 17] #B grade
```

I know I must be doing something wrong as I am still new to python, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really understand what exactly are you trying to accomplish here, so I'm making these assumptions:

1. Based on your expected output, I believe the values of n1 and n2 variables are swapped.
2. I don't know why it's necessary to use strings for the grades, so I'm assuming it's not.
3. I'm adding a few good practices to the code, so it becomes more readable and encapsulates the variables (I suggest reading [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Based on that, here's the code:

```
def listselect(scores, students, grades):
    """Group students and scores. Both lists must be the same size"""

    for index, score in enumerate(scores):
        for grade in grades:
            grade_list = grade[0]  # A, B
            min_value = grade[1]
            max_value = grade[2]

            if score in range(min_value, max_value):
                student = students[index]

                grade_list.append(student)
                grade_list.append(score)

    # Since lists are fetched from pointers, returning a list is not necessary,
    # but it makes the code more readable.
    return grades


def main():
    A, B = [], []

    # So I'm constructing a "package" with all the important bits
    # we need from the grades:
    # 1. The list containing the students within the grade (empty for now)
    # 2. The minimum value to fit this grade (i.e., min <= x)
    # 3. The maximum value to fit this grade (excluding the actual value, i.e., x < max)
    A_info = [A, 0, 10]
    B_info = [B, 10, 20]

    grades = [A_info, B_info]

    # Don't need to convert the list to string here
    scores = [13, 3, 17]
    students = ['mary', 'john', 'rob']

    grades = listselect(scores, students, grades)

    for grade in grades:
        print(grade[0])  # Print just the list
        print("\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! this is exactly what I was looking for. Just another query quickly, is there a way that the scores list would be able to accept variables with the value of a number?

Comment: @CrustyKing if you just replace the numbers with the variables containing them, the result will be the same

Answer (score 2):

Based on your ideal output, I assume that you've accidentally misordered john's and lucy's scores in your code sample.

You'll find it much easier to pair the score with the name rather than try to remember the order of variables. Also assuming there's some numeric test on the score to decide whether it's an A or a B - then you'd prefer it was an `int` (number) rather than a `str` (character string).

```
name_and_score_pairs = [
    ('john', 3),  # ('you', 'can', 'store', 'many', 'items', 'in', 'a', 'tuple')
    ('mary', 13),  # score not in quotes to treat as an integer
    ('rob', 17),
]

# you don't need these asserts - they just demonstrate how list/tuple indexing works
assert name_and_score_pairs[0] == ('john', 3)
assert name_and_score_pairs[0][0] == ('john')
assert name_and_score_pairs[0][1] == (3)
```

You can then write a function to process these scores in a single pass `for` loop. I've made up the criteria for an A grade as the score being less than 10 because I couldn't work out it what it was supposed to be from your code:

```
def group_names_by_score(names_and_scores_to_process):
    a_threshold = 10  # I've just made this score threshold up 
    a_grades, b_grades = [], []  # prepare the lists to put the names & scores into
    for name, score in names_and_scores_to_process:  # syntax sugar: tuple unpacking
        if score < a_threshold:  # if the student's score is less than 10 - then I assume it's an A
            a_grades.append(name)  # append name to a grade list
            a_grades.append(score)  # then append score to a grade list
        else:  # else it's a B
            b_grades.append(name)  # append name to b grade list
            b_grades.append(score)  # then append score to b grade list
    return a_grades, b_grades  # and finally return the two lists (as a tuple)
```

And finally pass the list you defined initially to the function above, assign the results to `A` and `B` and print the results:

```
# pass the names and scores you defined initially to the function
A, B = group_names_by_score(name_and_score_pairs)  # more tuple unpacking
print(A)
print(B)
```

The all together now:

```
name_and_score_pairs = [
    ('john', 3),  # ('you', 'can', 'store', 'many', 'items', 'in', 'a', 'tuple')
    ('mary', 13),  # score not in quotes to treat as an integer
    ('rob', 17),
]

# you don't need these asserts - they just demonstrate how list/tuple indexing works
assert name_and_score_pairs[0] == ('john', 3)
assert name_and_score_pairs[0][0] == ('john')
assert name_and_score_pairs[0][1] == (3)


def group_names_by_score(names_and_scores_to_process):
    a_threshold = 10  # I've just made this score threshold up 
    a_grades, b_grades = [], []  # prepare the lists to put the names & scores into
    for name, score in names_and_scores_to_process:  # syntax sugar: tuple unpacking
        if score < a_threshold:  # if the student's score is less than 10 - then I assume it's an A
            a_grades.append(name)  # append name to a grade list
            a_grades.append(score)  # then append score to a grade list
        else:  # else it's a B
            b_grades.append(name)  # append name to b grade list
            b_grades.append(score)  # then append score to b grade list
    return a_grades, b_grades  # and finally return the two lists (as a tuple)


# pass the names and scores you defined initially to the function
A, B = group_names_by_score(name_and_score_pairs)  # more tuple unpacking
print(A)
print(B)
```